# JDBC client reading data with out applying lock

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I am new to JDBC concepts. I have built a java client to read data from table using select query. To my knowledge when you perform a select query database will apply lock , which might imapct speed of inserts which are happening to table. Is there a way I can execute select query without applying locks. My Table is DB2 database.

Answer (score 0):

**Lock deferral with DB2_EVALUNCOMMITTED**

If you know your application behavior well, and you can tolerate the potential evaluation of query predicates against uncommitted data, then you should use lock deferral. Doing so may improve application concurrency.
DB2_EVALUNCOMMITTED allows scans with isolation level Cursor Stability (CS) or Read Stability (CS) to avoid or defer row locking until a data row is known to satisfy predicate evaluation. Rows which don't satisfy your query are bypassed.

For more information read the following article:

[DB2 concurrency](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0509schuetz/)